# Is there a way that i could sort items in datagrid Alphabetically in flex

Tags: apache-flex

I want to sort items in the datagrid alphabetically by name.The order should be:

1) The name should first check for upeercase of the name if it is not then it should look for lowercase for the same letter alphabetically.

For example : if i have array of items say{Apple,boy,ant,Bat) then after sorting the list shld be

Apple
ant
Bat
boy

Answer (score 1):

Use a collection class (ArrayCollection or XMLListCollection), then sort it.  More docs:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/about_dataproviders_4.html#441147

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/05/sorting-an-arraycollection-using-the-sortfield-and-sort-classes/

Comment: I am using a ListCollectionView and i have to apply the sorting for Row where i have custom ItemRenderer.

Comment: Great!  Does that mean your question is answered?

Answer (score 0):

```
<mx:DataGrid id="planGrid" width="100%" height="100%" sortableColumns="true" resizableColumns="true" dragMoveEnabled="false" dragEnabled="false" draggableColumns="false" dataProvider="{contrList.dataProvider}"click="{displayPropertiesForPlan(event);}">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn sortCompareFunction="compareTypes" headerText="{msg('planner.editplan.name')}" wordWrap="true" itemRenderer="net.velti.mgage.mkt.views.campaignplans.planlist.NameItemRenderer" />
        <mx:DataGridColumn width="200" headerText="{msg('planner.plans.grid.head.Status')}" itemRenderer="net.velti.mgage.mkt.views.campaignplans.planlist.StatusItemRenderer"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn id="dateColumn" width="250" headerText="{msg('planner.plans.grid.head.created')}" labelFunction="dateFunc" />
        <mx:DataGridColumn sortCompareFunction="sortBudget" id="budgetColumn" width="120" headerText="{msg('planner.plans.grid.head.BudgetWithSign')}" labelFunction="budgetFunc" />
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

My sort compare function is:

```
private function compareTypes(typeOne:Object, typeTwo:Object):int
{
    var nameA:String = typeOne.name;
    var nameB:String = typeTwo.name;
    return ObjectUtil.stringCompare(nameA,nameB);
}
```

This doesn't sort in alphabetical order.